# Error Converting Sparse Matrix to Array with scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.toarray()

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a [scipy.sparse.csc_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html) that I am trying to transform into an array with `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.toarray()`. When I use the function for a small dataset it works fine. However, when I use it for a large dataset, the python interpreter immediately crashes upon calling the function and the window closes without an error message.  The matrix I am trying to transform into an array was created with `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`. I am running python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04. To complicate matters, when I try to run the script from the terminal in order to save any error message, the log records no error message and indeed stops much earlier in the script (despite being complete if `toarray()` is not called).

Comment: If the variable holding your CSC matrix is called `mat`, can you print `mat.shape` and `mat.nnz` and share them here? Knowing the versions of `scipy` and `numpy` your system is running may also be relevant.

Comment: It was a version issue. `scipy` 0.9 did not work, updating to 0.14 did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call `toarray` on a large sparse matrix as it will try to store all the values (including the zeros) explicitly in a continuous chunk of memory.

Let's take and example, assume you have sparse matrix A:

```
>>> A.shape
(10000, 100000)
>>> A.nnz              # non zero entries
47231
>>> A.dtype.itemsize
8
```

The size of the non-zeros data in MB is:

```
>>> (A.nnz * A.dtype.itemsize) / 1e6
0.377848
```

You can check that this matches the size of the `data` array of the sparse matrix data-structure:

```
>>> A.data / 1e6
0.377848
```

Depending on the kind of sparse matrix data-structure (CSR, CSC, COO...), it also stores the location of the non-zero entries in various ways. In general this approximately doubles the memory usage. So the total memory used by A is in the order of 700kB.

Converting to the contiguous array representation would materialize all the zeros in memory and the resulting size would be:

```
>>> A.shape[0] * A.shape[1] * A.dtype.itemsize / 1e6
8000.0
```

That's 8GB for this example, compared to less than 1MB for the original sparse representation.

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was a version issue with scipy. Interestingly, when I follow your suggestion `A.shape[0] * A.shape[1] * A.dtype.itemsize / 1e6` to calculate memory requirements, I get a little under 27000 or 27GB. Yet, on a computer with only 16GB of RAM, `A.toarray()` works and executes instantaneously.

Comment: What does `A.toarray().nbytes / 1e6` returns then?

Comment: It returns the exact same value.

Comment: Well that's really weird, it should use 27GB or crash when calling `toarray()`.

Comment: When I tried converting sparse matrix to array using toarray() my Google colab session always getting crashed. Looks like on computer memory management might take care of processing large sparse matrices but on Google colab its not the case.

Answer (score -1):

just delete .toarray, and use sparse matrix as input to classifier, it works just fine