# Split a sparse matrix into chunks without converting to dense

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to split a sparse matrix (*type: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix*) into N parts in the right order and iterative over them to use them as inputs for classification prediction.

However, if I try to convert the sparse matrix to a dense matrix with `csr_matrix.toarray()`, I get a MemoryError. The size of the converted array would take up 70gb of RAM, tested with the method in this thread ([Error Converting Sparse Matrix to Array with scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.toarray()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500484/error-converting-sparse-matrix-to-array-with-scipy-sparse-csc-matrix-toarray))

So I can't use `numpy.array_split()` to split the array, because it only works on dense matrices.

Is there another way to split/slice the sparse matrix into N sparse matrices?

Thanks.

---

Additional edit:

So the chunking goes like this with a sparse array X_test:

```
# X_test is a sparse matrix with feature vectors

chunk_results = []
X_dense = csr_matrix.toarray(X_test)
X_test_chunks = np.array_split(X_dense, 20)
for chunk in X_test_chunks:
    chunk_results.append(classifier.predict(chunk))
prediction = np.concatenate(chunk_results)
```

Here an example of a conversion for a small sparse matrix to dense:

```
# sparse
(0, 0)  -0.5
(0, 1)  3.8570557155110414
(0, 2)  -1.975755301731886
(1, 0)  -3.5
(1, 1)  6.54336961554629
(1, 2)  -3.311314222363026

# dense
[[-0.5         3.85705572 -1.9757553 ]
 [-3.5         6.54336962 -3.31131422]]
```

Each of those two inner arrays in the dense matrix is a Feature-Vector representing one object. Basically, assuming we would try to classify those by doing the chunk split technique with conversion on this example, we would take n=2 and get [-0.5 3.85705572 -1.9757553] and [-3.5 6.54336962 -3.31131422] as two chunks. In case we would have a bigger matrix with more entries, there would be several of these vector-arrays per chunk.

---

**SOLUTION**

I made a workaround by dividing the number of rows of the sparse matrix with the desired number of chunks, and slice the matrix in chunks of rows of that number as hpaulj suggested:

> Blockquote
>   np.array_split does sliced indexing of the dense array, [arr[i:j] for i,j in ....]. So you could do the same sort of indexing on a csr matrix. Sparse slicing isn't as fast as the dense version, but it works (for the right sparse format).

Comment: What's the shape of your matrix, and desire shape and order of the chunks?

Comment: `np.array_split` does sliced indexing of the dense array, `[arr[i:j] for i,j in ....]`.  So you could do the same sort of indexing on a `csr` matrix.  Sparse slicing isn't as fast as the dense version, but it works (for the right sparse format).

Comment: Shape is something similar to (50000, 250000). The idea is to split the matrix into around 20 chunks and `model.predict(chunk)` for each of them, adding the resulting arrays of predicted targets to a temporary list and finally concatenate them into a `y_predicted` list after all predictions. The order of chunks must be kept the same as in the original sparse matrix for the predicted targets to be in the same order as the true ones when building the `classification_report(y_predicted, y_true)`.

Comment: Chunks - by row, column or a combination?

Comment: I believe a combination(?). I don't exactly understand how the sparse matrix is constructed by a FeatureUnion. However it contains the feature-vectors of the input, so at least their integrity has to be kept. I̶f̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶v̶e̶r̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶p̶a̶r̶s̶e̶ ̶m̶a̶t̶r̶i̶x̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶a̶ ̶d̶e̶n̶s̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶,̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶y̶i̶e̶l̶d̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶2̶D̶ ̶a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶`̶[̶ ̶[̶x̶1̶]̶ ̶[̶x̶2̶]̶.̶.̶ ̶.̶[̶x̶n̶]̶ ̶]̶.̶`̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶x̶i̶ ̶b̶e̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶f̶e̶a̶t̶u̶r̶e̶-̶v̶e̶c̶t̶o̶r̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶m̶u̶l̶t̶i̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶s̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶-̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶.̶

Comment: I'd suggest demonstrating this chunking on a small enough example that you can use dense arrays.  Then we can suggest ways of doing the same with a sparse matrix.  I realize with these big-data problems it is hard to provide [mcve], but we can't help when all we see are generalities.

Comment: I tried to explain it with a really small example in the original post, hope it helps. Would appreciate if you take a look.

Comment: The row slicing that I first suggested should work.  I wouldn't try to make a list of the chunks.

Comment: It worked out after I found out how to get the size of the sparse matrix so I could split the feature-vectors as desired. Thank you @hpaulj !